# Unable to Serve React App via NGINX Reverse Proxy in Dockerized Containers

Tags: reactjs, docker, nginx, proxy

I am working with a client trying to develop a PWA, which is new to me. The service workers all run in my local environment using Vite & React, but require https to illustrate in production.

I cannot get the assets to be correctly served for the client app through an nginx reverse proxy.

I have three containers, illustrated in the Docker Compose script below

###### compose.yml

```
version: '3'

services:
  proxy:
    build: ./nginx-proxy
    ports:
      - 80:80
    volumes:
      - ./nginx-proxy/nginx.conf:/etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf
    networks:
      - my-network

  root:
    build: ./root
    container_name: root
    networks:
      - my-network

  visit:
    build: ./client
    container_name: client
    networks:
      - my-network

networks:
  my-network:
```

I want the root to be available at servername.com/ and the client app to be available at servername.com/client.

I attempted to configure the nginx-proxy.conf to proxy_pass to the client docker container but it cannot find the assets. I've attempted to change the base path in vite, and it looks like it's going to load them, but I am getting a `Failed to load module script` error, which based on my reading is related to paths and not MIME types. I could be wrong here.

The following are my three Dockerfiles and nginx.conf files for the respective containers.

### ./nginx-proxy

##### Dockerfile

```
FROM nginx:latest
COPY nginx.conf /etc/nginx/conf.d/nginx.conf
EXPOSE 80
CMD ["nginx", "-g", "daemon off;"]
```

##### nginx.conf

```
server {
    listen  80;
    server_name localhost;

    proxy_set_header Host $host;
    proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Host $server_name;

    location / {
        proxy_pass http://root;
    }

    location /visit {
        proxy_pass http://client;
        proxy_redirect off;
    }
}
```

### clientapp

##### Dockerfile

```
FROM node:18-alpine as builder
WORKDIR /app
COPY package.json .
RUN npm i
COPY . .

RUN npm run build

FROM nginx:1.25.1-alpine as production
ENV NODE_ENV production
COPY --from=builder /app/dist /usr/share/nginx/html
COPY nginx.conf /etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf

EXPOSE 80

CMD [ "nginx", "-g", "daemon off;" ]
```

##### nginx.conf

```
server {
    listen  80;

    location / {
        root /usr/share/nginx/html;
        include /etc/nginx/mime.types;
        try_files $uri $uri/ /index.html;
    }
}
```

Any ideas why I'm not able to get the assets served correctly to the browser?

Both my root and the client apps use react-router-dom. I've tried to configure the basename for the react router for the client app to no avail.

```
const router = createBrowserRouter([
  {
    path: "/",
    basename: "/client",
    element: <App />,
    errorElement: <div>Error!</div>,
    children: [
      {index:true, element: <Home/>},
      {
        path: "/ar",
        element: <AR/>},
      {
        path: "/map",
        element: <Map/>},
      {
        path: "/list",
        element: <List/>},
    ]
  },
]);
```

I can provide more context if needed.

Comment: I get the same errors in Firefox and Chrome, related to MIME types, but my other app loads just fine so I have trouble believing that's the reason, unless something is getting garbled in the proxy. I think it just can't find the files.

Comment: I was able to load a plain html, but nothing in any of the subdirectories will load, even if I manually add them into the container.

Comment: I added this to block to the proxy nginx.conf and it seems to at least allowed the react app to load, but only the errorPage element and not anything in the router.

```
     location ~ /visitapp/(.*) {
        proxy_pass http://visitapp/$1;
    }

```

Comment: Can you upload your project to github or gitlab ? Maybe it is easier for other people to find out what the problem is